# 2D Quantum Hamonic oscillator in magnetic field with a shiftted position

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, gauge

**Background** 
Consider a hole in a 2D parabolic potential in a magnetic field which is generate by the following gauge:
$$
\vec{A} = \left( - \frac{B_z y}{2}, \frac{B_z x}{2},0\right)
$$
Our quantum Harmonic oscillator can be written as
$$
H = \frac{1}{2m_0} \left( \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} + \frac{e B_z y}{2} \right)^2 +\frac{1}{2m_0} \left( \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial y} - \frac{e B_z x}{2} \right)^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_0 \omega_0^2 x^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_0 \omega_0^2 y^2
$$
This famous problem can be solve by Fock-Darwin states, taking the ground state as an example
$$
\phi_0(x,y) = \frac{1}{R_{a,0} \sqrt{\pi}} \,\,\exp\left(- \frac{x^2+y^2}{2R_{a,0}^2}\right) \quad R_{a, 0}=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{m_0 \Omega_{0}}} \quad \Omega_{0}=\sqrt{\omega_{0}^2+\frac{1}{4} \omega_c} \quad \omega_c=\frac{e B_z}{m_0}
$$
which can give the ground state energy:
$$
\frac{B_z^2 e^2 R_{a,0}^2}{8 m_0} + \frac{1}{2} m_0 R_{a,0}^2 \omega_0^2 + \frac{\hbar^2}{2m_0 R_{a,0}^2}
$$

**Question**
Now let us shift the quantum Harmonic oscillator to the left by doing $x \rightarrow x+d_0$, where $d_0$ is a constant. Then our Hamiltonian will read:
$$
H' = \frac{1}{2m_0} \left( \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + \frac{e B_z y}{2} \right)^2 +\frac{1}{2m_0} \left( \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial y} - \frac{e B_z (x+d_0)}{2} \right)^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_0 \omega_0^2 (x+d_0)^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_0 \omega_0^2 y^2
$$
Correspondingly, the wavefunction has to be re-written as
$$
\phi'_0(x,y) = \frac{1}{R_{a,0} \sqrt{\pi}} \,\,\exp\left(- \frac{(x+d_0)^2+y^2}{2R_{a,0}^2}\right) \exp\left( -i \frac{d_0 y}{2R_B^2}\right) \quad R_B = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{m_0 \omega_c}}
$$
But now after I evaluate
$$
\langle \phi'_0 | H' | \phi'_0 \rangle = \frac{B_z^2 e^2 R_{a,0}^2}{8 m_0} + \frac{1}{2} m_0 R_{a,0}^2 \omega_0^2 + \frac{\hbar^2}{2m_0 R_{a,0}^2} + \frac{d_0^2 \hbar^2}{8 m_0 R_B^4}
$$
We can see clearly that after moving the H.O to the left, we get different groud state energy. Is it saying we get extra just by moving the H.O? I do not think this is a sensible answer. Can anyone help me to point out where the extra energy is from?

Or, Should we just argue that: As long as the energy difference between ground state and the first excited state is the same for two cases, the extra energy does not matter.

Comment: You forgot the $\pm i$'s in front of the partial derivatives. The sign depends on whether you have particles of charge $-e$ (eg electrons) or of charge $+e$ (eg electron holes). For your question, there is necessarily a mistake in your calculation.

Comment: Oh @LPZ, Thanks for pointing that out, I have made the corresponding changes everywhere, and emphasis the particle is a hole. The result is not altered.